# sql data base with pictures

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access-2010

I'm working on a SQL server database and I need to have pictures

its for a catalog and most pictures are 1-4 mbs I don't thing embedding the pictures in SQL will be a good idea

what the best solution
till now I used to use access

I would really like to make a wpf form
but when I make a data source I don't understand exactly how linked images work

my main point is that I need it to run really quick and print out a catalog with inventory info each day for thousands of items

I'm looking for a form to manage it

I have tried an access form but access doesn't handle good the linked pictures

Answer (score 0):

Just store the path to the image in the database.

Or, if using SQL 2008 or higher, there is also a new table called FileTable that stores data in the file system directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ff929144.aspx

"I need it to run really quick" If speed is a must, Access might not be a good choice for this.. You should use a more professional RDBMS, IMHO.

Comment: The RDBMS is SQL server, according to the OP, Access is simply the front end management, and quite useful as such.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a hobby project I'd suggest using sqlserver express (I assume you have microsoft knowledge) and either storing a link to an image on the file system/web server or storing the object in the db. For small data volumes either way is likely to perform fairly well.

Comment: Ans what are you suggesting for front-end?

Comment: If you're looking for a simple GUI look at Visual Studio lightswitch.  It's a little bit more robust than Access and handles pictures/images rather smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Lightswitch - it looks interesting providing a lot of the benefits of APEX on Oracle

Answer (score 0):

It is all very easy in MS Access 2010, just bind an image control to a table of paths. For example, my table is called Pictures, with the following entries.

```
PicturePath
Z:\Users\Fionnuala\Pictures\abc.png
Z:\Users\Fionnuala\Pictures\abc.jpg
```

I now just need an image control on a report bound to the table Pictures with a control source set to PicturePath, the images will be displayed.